# Why do different date math operations produce the same value?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date-math

I can add six days to a date and get what I expect, but if I add seven days to that same date, I get the same date.

What I mean is this; when the user has enter "*12/27/2015*" as the value for the @BegDate parameter, this declaration:

```
DECLARE 
@Week1End datetime = DATEADD(Day, 6, @BegDate),
@Week2Begin datetime = DATEADD(Day, 7, @BegDate);
```

...results in both @Week1End and @Week2Begin being the same date (2016-01-02), as you can see from the result set returned:

[image]

This is the TSQL:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[variancePriceByProductWithPriceChangePercentage]
    @Unit varchar(25),
    @BegDate datetime,
    @EndDate datetime
AS

DECLARE 
@Week1End datetime = DATEADD(Day, 6, @BegDate),
@Week2Begin datetime = DATEADD(Day, 7, @BegDate);

Select Ind.Description,
    @BegDate  BegDate,
    @Week1End Week1End,
    @Week1End Week2Begin,
    @EndDate EndDate,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.QtyShipped ELSE 0 END) 
Week1Usage,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.QtyShipped ELSE 0 END) 
Week2Usage,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) 
Week1Price,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) -
   SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.QtyShipped ELSE 0 END) 
UsageVariance,
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.QtyShipped ELSE 0 END) 
-
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) 
PriceVariance,
    (SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @Week2Begin AND @EndDate THEN Ind.QtyShipped ELSE 0 
END)  -
    SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END) )
    / 
NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @Week1End THEN Ind.Price ELSE 0 END),0) 
PercentageOfPriceVariance
    From    InvoiceDetail Ind
    Where   Ind.Unit = @Unit
    AND Ind.InvoiceDate BETWEEN @BegDate AND @EndDate
    Group By Ind.Description
```

So why does **@BegDate + 6** equate to the same thing as **@BegDate + 7**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Week1End Week1End,
@Week1End Week2Begin,
```

Look at this piece of code again...

Comment: Ah, that's it; I fixed that before, and another copy-and-paste job brought it back in. I'm now using LINQPad to delete and re-create the SPs, as that is easier than Server Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure:

```
DECLARE @BegDate datetime = GETDATE()

SELECT @BegDate, DATEADD(Day, 6, @BegDate), DATEADD(Day, 7, @BegDate);
```

Result:

[image]

I think your issue is here:

```
@Week1End Week1End,
@Week1End Week2Begin, ---<<<<<---
```

It should be :

```
@Week1End Week1End,
@Week2BeginWeek2Begin, ---<<<<<---
```

Comment: I know it seems to make no sense, but you can see the results I got above: Week1End and Week2Begin return the same value.